# Excel VBA - Order of cell filling from a User Form - seems almost random?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Maybe this post is a tad long but I hope you will read it and have some input for me.

I have been working to make a user form for Welder Qualification Test Records (WQTR).  Since the form is 107 fields, I have created a fairly involved Module that allows the user to save their progress.  Rather type lengthy explanations, I'm adding the completed Module here.  I have made detailed comments in the code but let me know if something needs explaining.

Everything compiles fine and it does what I expect it to do with one exception.  I assumed (not sure why) that the order the TextBoxes are being read by the script and entered into the worksheet (all in one row) would be in sync with the tab order.  However, that is not case.  In fact, I can see no particular order at all.  I think this has something to do with how I am creating the headers for columns based on the Labels in the user form, but I'm not sure.  I did make sure that the labels are in the proper order in the tab order even though I set all label's TabStop properties for to False.

Below is the code I have in the module.  I have several other modules but none of them should have any bearing on this issue.

```
  Option Explicit
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim welderNameEntered As String
Dim welderName_ As Variant
Dim welderFirstName As String
Dim welderMiddlename As String
Dim welderLastName As String
Dim sheetName As String
Dim arrayLength As Integer

'********************************************************************************
'***Controls the order of execution in this module for all Subs and Functions.***
'********************************************************************************

Public Sub TempSaveProgress()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call SplitName
    funcCheckAndAddNewSheet sheetName
    Call SaveData
    Call Protection.DangerMouse(sheetName)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

'************************************************************************************
'***Splits the Welders's first and last names by the space between them and grabs****
'***the first three characters of each.   Sets the value of the sheetname variable***
'************************************************************************************

Sub SplitName()
    welderNameEntered = WQTR_Form.welderNameText.Value
    welderName_ = Split(welderNameEntered, " ")
    Dim arrayLength As Integer
    arrayLength = UBound(welderName_) - LBound(welderName_) + 1
    Dim answer As Long

        If arrayLength = 0 Then
            Call ArrayLengthZero
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf arrayLength = 1 Then
            Call ArrayLengthOneAndThree
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf arrayLength = 2 Then
            welderFirstName = Left(welderName_(0), 3)
            welderLastName = Left(welderName_(1), 3)
            sheetName = "Temp-" + welderLastName + "-" + welderFirstName
        ElseIf arrayLength = 3 Then
            welderFirstName = Left(welderName_(0), 3)
            welderMiddlename = Left(welderName_(1), 1)
            welderLastName = Left(welderName_(2), 3)
            sheetName = "Temp-" + welderLastName + "-" + welderFirstName + "-" + welderMiddlename
        ElseIf arrayLength > 3 Then
            Call ArrayLengthOneAndThree
            Exit Sub
        End If

End Sub

'**************************************************************************************
'***Adds and new worksheet after all other worksheets and gives it a temporary name.***
'**************************************************************************************

Function funcCheckAndAddNewSheet(argCheckAndAdd As String)
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If argCheckAndAdd = ws.Name Then
            Call SheetNameAlreadyExists
        End If
    Next ws
    If sheetName <> "" Then
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = argCheckAndAdd
    End If
End Function

'*****************************************
'***Message if the arrayLength is zero ***
'*****************************************

Sub ArrayLengthZero()
    Dim answer As Long
    answer = MsgBox("You must enter a welder's name in order to Save Your Progress.", vbOKOnly, "No name?")
End Sub

'**************************************************
'***Message if the arrayLength is One or Three. ***
'**************************************************

Sub ArrayLengthOneAndThree()
    Dim answer As Long
    answer = MsgBox("The Welder's Name you entered is not valid.  The name must conform to one these examples:" + _
                                vbNewLine + vbNewLine + _
                                "    1. FirstName LastName as in John Doe." + vbNewLine + _
                                "    2. FirstName MiddleName LastName as in Franklin Deleno Roosevilt." + vbNewLine + _
                                "    3. FirstName MiddleInitial LastName as in Joe D. Public." + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + _
                                "You also must make sure that names are no more than three names.  " + _
                                "A name such as Roy Wayne David Johnson will not work.  " + _
                                "In such cases, one of the two middle names must be omitted." _
                                , vbOKOnly, "Name is incorrect")
End Sub

'******************************************************************************
'***Message if sheetName matches the name of an already existing worksheet. ***
'******************************************************************************

Sub SheetNameAlreadyExists()
    Dim answer As Long
        answer = MsgBox("A WorkSheet by by the name " + sheetName + " already exists." + _
                        "  Did you already Save Progress for this welder on another occasion?" + _
                        "  If so, would you like to overwrite the data in the Worksheet named " + _
                        sheetName + "?", vbYesNo, sheetName + " Already Exists.")
            If answer = vbYes Then
            Call SafeMouse
            Worksheets(sheetName).Activate
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Worksheets(sheetName).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Exit Sub
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
End Sub


'****************************************************************************************
'***Sets the Active Sheet for all of the subs it calls. Again, this basically         ***
'***controls the order of execution. Then does some minor worksheet level formatting. ***
'****************************************************************************************

Private Sub SaveData()
    Worksheets(sheetName).Activate
    Call LabelNames
    Call LabelCaptions
    Call TextBoxText
    Call DeleteEmptyColumns

    '-----Worksheet-level Formatting-----
    Worksheets(sheetName).range("A1:DD1").Font.Bold = True
    Worksheets(sheetName).Columns("A:DD").AutoFit

End Sub

'***************************************************************************************
'***Takes the names of all of the form lables and enters them in the first row of the***
'***active sheet.                                                                    ***
'***************************************************************************************

Private Sub LabelNames()
    Dim ctlLblName As control
    Dim col As Integer: col = 0

    For Each ctlLblName In WQTR_Form.Controls
        If TypeName(ctlLblName) = "Label" Then
            col = col + 1
            Cells(1, col).Value = ctlLblName.Name
            Cells(1, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        End If
    Next ctlLblName
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************************
'***Takes the captions of all of the form lables and enters them in the second row of the***
'***active sheet.                                                                        ***
'*******************************************************************************************

Private Sub LabelCaptions()
    Dim ctlLblCaption As control
    Dim col As Integer: col = 0

    For Each ctlLblCaption In WQTR_Form.Controls
        If TypeName(ctlLblCaption) = "Label" Then
            col = col + 1
            Cells(2, col).Value = ctlLblCaption.Caption
            Cells(2, col).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next ctlLblCaption
End Sub

'***************************************************************************************************
'***The Label Names and the TextBox Names were made to be identical except for the last part of  ***
'***the names which are "Label" and "Text", respectively.  This code finds all TextBox Names,     ***
'***strips "Text" out of the TexBox Name and replaces it with "Label" which makes it identical   ***
'***to the Label Name.  Then it searches for the label name in the active sheet.  When a match   ***
'***found it inserts the TextBox.Text Value (entered by the user) in the cell in row three.      ***
'***************************************************************************************************


Private Sub TextBoxText()
    Dim ctlTxtBx As control
    Dim col As Variant: col = 0
    Dim strTextBoxName As String
    Dim strShortenedTxtBxName As String
    Dim strConvertedTxtBxName As String

    For Each ctlTxtBx In WQTR_Form.Controls
        If TypeName(ctlTxtBx) = "TextBox" Then
            strTextBoxName = ctlTxtBx.Name
            strShortenedTxtBxName = Left(strTextBoxName, Len(strTextBoxName) - 4)
            strConvertedTxtBxName = strShortenedTxtBxName + "Label"
            col = Application.Match(strConvertedTxtBxName, Worksheets(sheetName).Rows(1), 0)
            col = CInt(col)
            Cells(3, col).Value = ctlTxtBx.Text
        End If
    Next ctlTxtBx
End Sub

'******************************************************************************************************
'***Search columns from A through DF (110) and deletes columns where the cell in row three is empty.***
'******************************************************************************************************

Private Sub DeleteEmptyColumns()
    Dim col As Integer
    For col = 110 To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(3, col) = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(col).Delete
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```

So, what I would have expected based on Tab order, is the following

```
'| welderNameLabel | testDateLabel | wqtrNumberLabel | shopLabel | companyNameLabel | revisionNumberLabel | wpsNumberLabel | bm1_specificationLabel |
'|---------------- | ------------- | --------------- | --------- | ---------------- | ------------------- | -------------- | ---------------------- |
'| Welder Name     | Test Date     | WQTR Number     | Shop      | Company Name     | Revision Number     | WPS Number     | Specification          |
'|---------------- | ------------- | --------------- | --------- | ---------------- | ------------------- | -------------- | ---------------------- |
'| Dean Marin      | 5-23-2017     | DM-1234-6G-FCAW | Bravo     | ABC Company      | Rev. 0              | 12345          | AWS D1.1 Code          |
```

What I actually get is like this:

```
'| testDateLabel | welderNameLabel | companyNameLabel | shopLabel | wqtrNumberLabel | revisionNumberLabel | wpsNumberLabel | bm1_specificationLabel |
'| ------------- | --------------- | ---------------- | --------- | --------------- | ------------------- | -------------- | ---------------------- |
'| Test Date     | Welder Name     | Company Name     | Shop      | WQTR Number     | Revision Number     | WPS Number     | Specification          |
'| ------------- | --------------- | ---------------- | --------- | --------------- | ------------------- | -------------- | ---------------------- |
'| 5-23-2017     | Dean Marin      | ABC Company      | Bravo     | DM-1234-6G-FCAW | Rev. 0              | 12345          | AWS D1.1 Code          |
```

I have tested this many many times and it always puts the data in the worksheet in the exact same order.  I could write some code to sort it the order I want but before I do that I wanted to post this question to see if anyone has any ideas about why it behaves this way.  I am a bit concerned that I will write something to sort the columns and then later find that my experiments were misleading and the order of the data entry really is more random than it appears.

I code have simply written a line of code for every TextBox in the User Form and explicitly specified the exact cell where the data should go, but I wanted something more general I could adapt in other workbooks which I have planned, as they are all related to each other - (Welding Procedures, Procedure Qualifications and Welder Qualification Continuity Logs).

Perhaps there is some method someone knows of controlling this this order before the data is entered rather than doing some kind of sorting operations after the fact?

I appreciate any responses.

**UPDATE and ANSWER**

I agree with jsotola that it has to be they are ordered in accordance with the order they were created.  jsotola provided some code to list the order and I ran it multiple times and always got the exact same list in the exact same order.

Mystery solved!

If you are interested, here is the list.  Part of the reason I agree so strongly with the answer is that, from memory, I can say this is the order I added the controls to the form.  If you skim the controls you will see that there is a logical grouping of the names.  They are related to each other as you read down the list.

```
bm1_tubeSizeText
bm1_pipeFrame
bm1_pipeDiameterLabel
bm1_pipeDiameterText
baseMetalFrame2
bm2_baseMetalListBox
bm2_specificationLabel
bm2_specificationText
bm2_awsGroupNumberText
bm2_awsGroupNumberLabel
bm2_gradeLabel
bm2_gradeText
bm2_plateFrame
bm2_plateThicknessLabel
bm2_plateThicknessText
bm2_tubeFrame
bm2_tubeWallThicknessLabel
bm2_tubeWallThicknessText
bm2_tubeSizeLabel
bm2_tubeSizeText
bm2_pipeFrame
bm2_pipeSizeLabel
bm2_pipeSizeText
bm2_pipeSheduleLabel
bm2_pipeSheduleText
bm2_pipeDiameterLabel
bm2_pipeDiameterText
actualTestValuesFrame
atv_TypeOfWeldJointText
atv_filletPipeDiameterText
atv_filletPipeDiameterLabel
atv_baseMetalLabel
atv_baseMetalText
atv_filletFrame
atv_filletPipeTubeThicknessLabel
atv_filletPipeTubeThicknessText
atv_filletPlateThicknessLabel
atv_filletPlateThicknessText
atv_weldingFrame
atv_processLabel
atv_processText
atv_TypeOfWeldJointLabel
atv_grooveFrame
atv_groovePipeTubeThicknessLabel
atv_groovePipeTubeThicknessText
atv_groovePlateThicknessLabel
atv_groovePlateThicknessText
atv_groovePipeDiameterLabel
atv_groovePipeDiameterText
atv_processTypeLabel
atv_processTypeText
atv_backingLabel
atv_backingText
atv_weldingProcessFrame
atv_InstructionLabel_1
atv_InstructionLabel_2
atv_fillerMetalFrame
atv_awsSpecLabel
atv_awsSpecText
atv_awsClassificationLabel
atv_awsClassificationText
atv_fNumberLabel
atv_fNumberText
atv_positionFrame
atv_positionWeldedLabel
atv_positionWeldedText
rq_transferModeLabel
rq_transferModeText
rq_progressionLabel
rq_progressionText
atv_InstructionLabel_3
rq_InstructionLabel_4
rq_InstructionLabel_5
rq_singleOrMultipleElectrodesLabel
rq_singleOrMultipleElectrodesText
rq_gasFluxTypeLabel
rq_gasFluxTypeText
rangesQualiifedFrame
rq_weldingFrame
rq_weldingProcessFrame
rq_processLabel
rq_processText
rq_processTypeLabel
rq_processTypeText
rq_backingLabel
rq_backingText
rq_InstructionLabel_1
rq_InstructionLabel_2
rq_fillerMetalFrame
rq_awsSpecLabel
rq_awsSpecText
rq_awsClassificationLabel
rq_awsClassificationText
rq_fNumberLabel
rq_fNumberText
rq_positionFrame
rq_groovePipe24DownLabel
rq_groovePipe24DownText
rq_groovePlatePipe24UpLabel
rq_groovePlatePipe24UpText
rq_filletPlatePipe24UpLabel
rq_filletPlatePipe24UpText
rq_filletPipe24DownLabel
rq_filletPipe24DownText
rq_TypeOfWeldJointLabel
rq_TypeOfWeldJointText
rq_baseMetalLabel
rq_baseMetalText
rq_filletFrame
rq_filletPipeTubeThicknessLabel
rq_filletPipeTubeThicknessText
rq_filletPlateThicknessLabel
rq_filletPlateThicknessText
rq_filletPipeDiameterLabel
rq_filletPipeDiameterText
rq_grooveFrame
rq_groovePipeTubeThicknessLabel
rq_groovePipeTubeThicknessText
rq_groovePlateThicknessLabel
rq_groovePlateThicknessText
rq_groovePipeDiameterLabel
rq_groovePipeDiameterText
atv_gasFluxTypeText
atv_transferModeLabel
atv_transferModeText
atv_progressionLabel
atv_progressionText
atv_InstructionLabel_4
atv_InstructionLabel_5
atv_singleOrMultipleElectrodesLabel
atv_singleOrMultipleElectrodesText
atv_gasFluxTypeLabel
testResultsFrame
acceptanceCriteria_1Label
acceptanceCriteria_1Text
typeOfTest_1Label
typeOfTest_1Text
results_1Label
results_1Text
remarks_1Label
remarks_1Text
acceptanceCriteria_3Text
typeOfTest_3Text
results_3Text
remarks_3Text
acceptanceCriteria_2Text
typeOfTest_2Text
results_2Text
remarks_2Text
acceptanceCriteria_4Text
typeOfTest_4Text
results_4Text
remarks_4Text
acceptanceCriteria_5Text
typeOfTest_5Text
results_5Text
remarks_5Text
certificationFrame
laboratoryLabel
laboratoryText
testConductedByLabel
testNumberLabel
testNumberText
fileNumberLabel
fileNumberText
certStatementLabel_1
codeYearText
certStatementLabel_2
certStatementLabel_3
manufacturerOrContractorLabel
manufacturerOrContractorText
authorizedByLabel
authorizedByText
dateLabel
dateText
finishFrame
finishInstructionsLabel
saveProgressButton
rq_positionsQualifiedFrame
testConductedByText
AbortButton
typeOfTest_2Label
acceptanceCriteria_2Label
results_2Label
remarks_2Label
typeOfTest_3Label
typeOfTest_4Label
typeOfTest_5Label
acceptanceCriteria_3Label
acceptanceCriteria_4Label
acceptanceCriteria_5Label
results_3Label
results_4Label
results_5Label
remarks_3Label
remarks_4Label
remarks_5Label
WelderIDLabel
WelderIDText
```

Comment: Just a question, where did you read that the order of the controls in the `.Controls` collection is in sync with their Tab-Stop order?? Never heard of that.

Comment: As i said in my post, I kind of assumed it!  I should have learned years ago never to assume anything!  So, it would be nice to understand how excel decided which order to put things in since I am not telling any particular order in my code.

Comment: put `Debug.Print ctlLblName.Name` in `Sub LabelNames()` after the _For Each ..._ line. that should print the order that the controls are queried.  it is probably the order that the controls were created .... now that i think about it  ... yes it is the order that the controls were created

Comment: Most likely the order of creation, although this feature is not documented. However nothing prevents you from creating **your own collection** (or array) with the order you desire, and later iterate on this custom collection.

Comment: you can copy the form controls one by one into a new form. that would change the order-of-creation, but if you ever needed to add another field to the form, the order would break again. your best bet is to do as @A.S.H suggests and create a custom collection

Comment: are the textboxes on the form all the same size in a column?  ... one thought is to use the _Tag_ property of each control

Comment: No the controls are all over the place..I have a MultiPage control and several frames and a couple of ListBoxes as well.  I expect that as I go forward and add some the background logic for validating input and then auto-filling based on input (see my comment further down the page) that some the TextBoxes will be replaced by Textboxes mated with SpinButtons, ListBoxes or maybe ComboBoxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will show the order-of-creation of the form controls

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()    ' runs when form background is clicked

    Stop             ' put here so that the code window shows up ( press F8 or F5 to continue)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UserForm1.Controls.Count - 1
        Debug.Print UserForm1.Controls(i).Name
    Next i
    stop
End Sub
```

Comment: That answer definitely makes sense.  It did not occur to me that order of creation would be the deciding factor but I suppose that (her comes another assumption on my part!)  that excel somehow creates it's own internal list of the controls as they are added so the order of that list should not change.  I will try the sample code you posted and post the results here.

Comment: Quick question for all reading this:  I'm pretty new at this programming thing.  I am on my own as well.  that is, nobody i know does any programming.  So it would be nice to get some feed back from others regarding style, the ways I have chosen to accomplish things, etc.  I am certain that there are much better ways to do it as I am not writing any classes, or really leveraging object oriented techniques.  But beyond the monolithic nature of my code, any comments/critique would be helpful to me in general.

Comment: @JesseSloan if I had to do this, I think I would make some worksheet itself as a user-form. with some technique and art you can make it user-friendly and nice, and it's very easy to save it...

Comment: Yes, I considered doing just that.  since there are many related forms I am going to be building and they all use similar data it is ultimately the plan to be able to reuse the components of each.  Also, when the forms are completed, I want to add some logic that will validate user input based on welding code requirements.  For example, if a welder welds T-Joint with a fillet weld in the horizontal position and the user attempt to enter that the welder is qualified to weld in the overhead position the logic of the background code would prevent it or maybe even auto-fill the qualified field.

Comment: @JesseSloan, your code is clearly written and it is far from monolithic. one thing i noticed, you use label names in order to fill the worksheet with data from the form. i think that you should use the text box names instead. you can use the _**Tag**_ property of each control to pass data (i am still trying to wrap my head around how to pair up labels and text boxes on a form ... it is so much easier if you use ms Access database )

Comment: ... one thing you could do is. put the textbox control name into the _**Text**_ property of each _TextBox_ control, and the label control name into the _**Label**_ property of each _Label_ control (just the paired up labels). that way you could see all the label names and all textbox names at a glance when you design the form.  then put the label caption, for the associated label, in the _TextBox.Tag_ property. ... in _Sub UserForm_Initialize()_ , delete content of all text boxes and fill text label caption  from _TextBox.Tag_

Comment: @jsotola I appreciate the feedback and your suggestions.  This all sort of evolved in an inside-out fashion.  In other words, I started off by getting the caption property of the labels because it seemed easiest as the text was already formatted like what I would normally write as a column header.  Then I captured the labels names and then focused on matching the textbox content to the label names.  You are correct.  I could have just used the testbox name and skipped some the string manipulation I did.  Also, I will definitely look at using the tag property as you described.  Again, thanks.